# Using BinaryFormatter and XmlSerializer interchangeably

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, binaryformatter

I've inherited a large amount of code that uses BinaryFormatter for serialization, that I now need to debug. All the serialization code currently expects an IFormatter.

I had a idea to replace the BinaryFormatter with an XmlSerializer, to make examining the serialized output easier, but they aren't compatible (no common base or interface).

Is there a standard approach to this e.g. make the parameter some kind of generic serializer that my code can use? Ideally I'd like to create whichever concrete serializer I want at the top level, and then it pass it down without the lower levels needing to know the concrete type.

Example of what I currently have:

```
BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();     //create a binary formatter
PutPw(bformatter, stream, panel.DevicePassword);    //encode and stream the password

public static void PutPw(IFormatter bf, Stream stream, string pw)
{
    ...
    bf.Serialize(stream, pw);
}
```

Comment: XML serialization is not compatible with binary formatting, not every binary-formattable object tree can be serealized as XML :(

Comment: So is the issue testing - that is you need to fake a serializer so that you can test your code.  Or is is that you want to be able to plug in some other serializer in place of the binary serializer?

Comment: @ScruffyDuck: Well both really, in the short term I just want to replace the BinaryFormatter to debug the code - in the long term I'd like to be able to select the serializer at runtime, depending on the customers requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has already been pointed out, not all objects that are binary serializable, are also XML serializable (for example, anything with TimeSpan).

But if you can deal with that pretty serious flaw, then the approach I would probably take is to create my own interface. I would then have 2 classes that implement it, one wrapping the binary formatter and one wrapping the XML serializer. To make life easier, have the interface very similar to the binary formatter in terms of method names your app uses and parameters so that you can replace occurrences of the concrete binary formatter relatively painlessly.

Comment: Yes sounds good. Then I can put any XML error handling due to serialization fails in my concrete xml wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked `SoapFormatter`? Not so readable like XmlSerializer but still XML, and you can understand most of the values. And it inherits from IFormatter, as BinaryFormatter does. So you can change to without need to touch your code.
And more, XmlSerializer can handle only public properties, of objects that have a parameterless constructor, while IFormatters work with reflection and can handle private fields and objects with a parameterized contructor. In addition the attribute `Serializable` can work with formatters only and not with XmlSerializer. It's fundmentally different, and you might have to change a lot of code.

Comment: Yes good answer (+1), but i already tried SoapFormatter, and no it's not very readable. It also doesn't always add the correct variable name when i serialized through it. It was good for a quick test though, as like you say, its also derived from IFormatter.

Comment: @Surfbutler From my experiance the names are ok. The incorrect names might be because the class author implemented `Iserializeble` and gave another name in the custom serialization. Not sure if it helps you.

Comment: Another way to produce readable streams without to break existing code is the hard way- implement a IFormatter of your own. [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/luskan/archive/2007/07/16/113956.aspx) is a little example.

Comment: Thanks. Re iserializable, one of the variables was being serialized as 'm_value' and that name isnt anywhere in our code (our variable name is different). Re iformatter, ok cool, i'll check out the example, cheers.

Comment: Just realised why the variable names looked wrong in the soap file - the build process obfuscates the executable!